# Razor: Why can this razor button not remove the desired entities from a list by index in the view page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have the following form for the user to create an instance of a class that contains a nested list. Both external and internal lists can be of varying length so I have added functionality for the user to extend both lists. Here is what the form panel for editing the lists looks like:

[image]

The buttons to add PINs and LINs work as intended adding a new object to the end of the list. However the buttons to remove PINs and LINs are not functioning as I intend them to. From the above picture the 'trash' button next to each PIN/LIN should remove that entry. However, the PIN trash button removes the last PIN in the list and the LIN trash button removes the last LIN from the correct PIN object. so for example pressing the LIN trash button for the LIN with value 4 in the image results in the following:

[image]

So it has instead removed the last LIN. If I next press the trash icon next to the second PIN entry the result is so:

[image]

The third PIN entry looks to have been removed and somehow there is a 9 added to the end the LIN list of the second PIN entry. I do not understand what is happening, but I suspect it has something to do with the binding as in the c# code behind the page everything is working as intended. (Note: When I press to remove the second PIN before removing a LIN then the last PIN is removed and not LIN entries are changed) Below shows the nested list in the debugger after the remove PIN operation described above is performed:

[image]

Here the correct PIN entry is removed but the page displays a very different result. Here is the Model

```
public class MatchingInputModel<T>
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public ApplicantDetails Applicant { get; set; }
        
        [BindProperty]
        public List<T> PinData { get; set; }
        
        [BindProperty]
        public AddressControlFlags ControlFlags { get; set; }
    }
```

The code in my razor page for the panel and buttons is as follows:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>PINs</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @for (var pinIndex = 0; pinIndex < Model._input.PinData.Count; pinIndex++)
            {
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <label>PIN</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <input asp-for="@Model._input.PinData[pinIndex].PIN" class="list-group"/>
                            <button asp-page-handler="DeletePin" type="submit" asp-route-pinIndex="@pinIndex">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <label>LINs</label>
                        @for (var linIndex = 0; linIndex < Model._input.PinData[pinIndex].LINs.Count; linIndex++)
                        {
                            <div class="row">
                                <input asp-for="@Model._input.PinData[pinIndex].LINs[linIndex]" class="list-group" placeholder="@Model._input.PinData[pinIndex].LINs[linIndex]"/>
                                <button asp-page-handler="DeleteLin" type="submit" asp-route-pinIndex="@pinIndex" asp-route-linIndex="@linIndex">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <button asp-page-handler="AddLin" type="submit" asp-route-pinIndexToAddLin="@pinIndex">Add LIN</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            }
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button asp-page-handler="AddPin" type="submit">Add PIN</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The DeleteLin() and DeletePin() mecshtml.cs file:

```
public IActionResult OnPostDeleteLin(int pinIndex, int linIndex)
        {
            _input.PinData[pinIndex].LINs.RemoveAt(linIndex);

            return Page();
        }
        
        public IActionResult OnPostDeletePin(int pinIndex)
        {
            _input.PinData.RemoveAt(pinIndex);

            return Page();
        }
```

Where `PinData` and `LINs` are both `List<T>` and `RemoveAt()` is `List<T>.RemoveAT()`. I cannot figure out why this is working the way it is, and how to get the functionality that I require. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to share your `DeleteLin` and `DeletePin` handler,and `_input.PinData.RemoveAt()`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the handlers, but `RemoveAt()` is the `List<T>` method